# Image Network Not Showing Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, image, dart

I am trying to load an image in every container upon user scroll but that image isn't showing up. I am trying to display a image that is fetched by a url. I basically want to display an image from google using Image.network. (Some more text because I don't have enough text to post because stack overflow is stupid)

Here is my code. Thanks!

```
class NewsFeed extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  GetNews createState() => GetNews();
}

class GetNews extends State<NewsFeed> {
  var _posts;

  bool _hasNextPage = true;
  bool _isFirstLoadRunning = false;
  bool _isLoadMoreRunning = false;

  void _loadMore() async {
    if (_hasNextPage == true &&
        _isLoadMoreRunning == false &&
        _controller.position.extentAfter < 300) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoadMoreRunning = true; // Display a progress indicator at the bottom
      }); // Increase _page by 1

      try {
        var res = [
          {
            'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
            'by': ' ',
            'intro-text':
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
            'image':
                'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
          },
          {
            'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
            'by': ' ',
            'intro-text':
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
            'image':
                'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
          }
        ];
        if (res.isNotEmpty) {
          setState(() {
            _posts.addAll(res);
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _hasNextPage = false;
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        print('Something went wrong!');
      }

      setState(() {
        _isLoadMoreRunning = false;
      });
    }
  }

  void start() {
    _posts = [
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
        'image':
            'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
        'image':
            'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
        'image':
            'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
        'image':
            'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
        'image':
            'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
        'image':
            'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
        'image':
            'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.',
        'image':
            'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg'
      },
    ];

    setState(() {
      _isFirstLoadRunning = false;
    });
  }

  late ScrollController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isFirstLoadRunning = true;
    start();
    _controller = ScrollController()..addListener(_loadMore);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _isFirstLoadRunning
        ? const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _posts.length,
                  controller: _controller,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) => Card(
                    margin:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 10),
                    child: Column(children: [
                      Image.network(
                          'https://media.self.com/photos/6398b36c72eb56f726777d06/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/weekly-workout-schedule.jpeg',
                          width: 100),
                      Text(_posts[index]['title'] as String),
                      Text(_posts[index]['intro-text'] as String),
                    ]),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (_isLoadMoreRunning == true)
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 40),
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                ),
              if (_hasNextPage == false)
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 40),
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('You have fetched all of the content'),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to completely wipe my emulator data, and then restart the app completely. You can do this in Android Studio by going to device manager, then press cold boot now.

Comment: your code is fine.. your code doesn't need any help..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StackOverFlowProblem extends StatefulWidget {
  const StackOverFlowProblem({super.key});

  @override
  State<StackOverFlowProblem> createState() => _StackOverFlowProblemState();
}

class _StackOverFlowProblemState extends State<StackOverFlowProblem> {
  var _posts;

  bool _hasNextPage = true;
  bool _isFirstLoadRunning = false;
  bool _isLoadMoreRunning = false;

  void _loadMore() async {
    if (_hasNextPage == true &&
        _isLoadMoreRunning == false &&
        _controller.position.extentAfter < 300) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoadMoreRunning = true; // Display a progress indicator at the bottom
      }); // Increase _page by 1

      try {
        var res = [
          {
            'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
            'by': ' ',
            'intro-text':
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna.',
            'image':
                'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO-hlLa1mnf2V1p__dFMxkNjf44wHphOxH2g&usqp=CAU'
          },
          {
            'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
            'by': ' ',
            'intro-text':
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna.',
            'image':
                'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO-hlLa1mnf2V1p__dFMxkNjf44wHphOxH2g&usqp=CAU'
          }
        ];
        if (res.isNotEmpty) {
          setState(() {
            _posts.addAll(res);
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _hasNextPage = false;
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        print('Something went wrong!');
      }

      setState(() {
        _isLoadMoreRunning = false;
      });
    }
  }

  void start() {
    _posts = [
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna.',
        'image':
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO-hlLa1mnf2V1p__dFMxkNjf44wHphOxH2g&usqp=CAU'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna.',
        'image':
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO-hlLa1mnf2V1p__dFMxkNjf44wHphOxH2g&usqp=CAU'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna.',
        'image':
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO-hlLa1mnf2V1p__dFMxkNjf44wHphOxH2g&usqp=CAU'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna.',
        'image':
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO-hlLa1mnf2V1p__dFMxkNjf44wHphOxH2g&usqp=CAU'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna.',
        'image':
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO-hlLa1mnf2V1p__dFMxkNjf44wHphOxH2g&usqp=CAU'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna.',
        'image':
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO-hlLa1mnf2V1p__dFMxkNjf44wHphOxH2g&usqp=CAU'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna.',
        'image':
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO-hlLa1mnf2V1p__dFMxkNjf44wHphOxH2g&usqp=CAU'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Skull Crushers vs. Tricep Pulldown',
        'by': ' ',
        'intro-text':
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna.',
        'image':
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO-hlLa1mnf2V1p__dFMxkNjf44wHphOxH2g&usqp=CAU'
      },
    ];

    setState(() {
      _isFirstLoadRunning = false;
    });
  }

  late ScrollController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isFirstLoadRunning = true;
    start();
    _controller = ScrollController()..addListener(_loadMore);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _isFirstLoadRunning
        ? const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _posts.length,
                  controller: _controller,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) => Card(
                    margin:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 10),
                    child: Column(children: [
                      Image(
                        width: 100,
                        image: NetworkImage(_posts[index]['image']),
                      ),
                      Text(_posts[index]['title'] as String),
                      Text(_posts[index]['intro-text'] as String),
                    ]),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (_isLoadMoreRunning == true)
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 40),
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                ),
              if (_hasNextPage == false)
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 40),
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('You have fetched all of the content'),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).